# Windows cmd pass value in chain/multiple command

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to get the last 10 lines of a file using [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt), [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).exe.

I am able to get the number of lines in the file using the `for` loop/delim. The problem is I need to subtract `10` from `%G` and pass that to the chained `more` command. But the variable `last10` is either not getting `set` or not passing to the `more` command.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %G IN ('find /v /c "" file.log') DO (set /a "last10=%G-10" & more file.log +%last10%)
```

How can I get the variable `last10` correctly in the `more` command?

Comment: classic [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) failure. Any specific reason to do it on command line instead of a short batch script?

Comment: I need to call this command from node.js exec call. I am not allowed to create a batch file. How can I fix this?

Comment: Got it. I added cmd /V:ON /C before the set and it worked. Thank you!